# jQuery sortable with serialize on a table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table:

```
<table class="products">
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tfoot>...</tfoot>

    <tbody id="the-list">
      <tr id="order-0">
        <th scope="row" class="check-column">stuff</th>
        <td class="title column-title">stuff</td>
        <td class="order column-order">stuff</td>
        <td class="display column-display">stuff</td>
        <td class="action column-action">stuff</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="order-1">
        <th scope="row" class="check-column">stuff</th>
        <td class="title column-title">stuff</td>
        <td class="order column-order">stuff</td>
        <td class="display column-display">stuff</td>
        <td class="action column-action">stuff</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="order-2">
        <th scope="row" class="check-column">stuff</th>
        <td class="title column-title">stuff</td>
        <td class="order column-order">stuff</td>
        <td class="display column-display">stuff</td>
        <td class="action column-action">stuff</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I use "sortable" with default everything, all is well:

```
jQuery('table.products tbody').sortable();
```

now when I try to serialize, all sortable functionality disappears and the table is static (no errors though...)

```
jQuery('table.products tbody').sortable('serialize');
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you do both ? First initialize with `.sortable()` and then call the method with `.sortable('serialize')`? If you do only the second, the plugin will not initilize and nothing will actually happen.

Comment: Well now I just feel silly. I can't accept a comment as an answer now can I?

Comment: No you can't, I have posted an answer ;-)

Comment: No; but you can upvote it to the moon, and so I can I!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your question, it seems you don't initialize your plugin prior to trying to use a method from it.

You have to first init the plugin with `.sortable()` and then you can call methods like `.sortable('serialize')`.

```
var $table = jQuery('table.products tbody');

$table.sortable();
$table.sortable('serialize');
```

Comment: Chain this method to reduce overhead. $("element").sortable().sortable('serialize');

Comment: @Ohgodwhy. Yes you could (should) chain, for the sake of the example, I have made into two statements.

Comment: Yup. I still upvoted for sure. Just adding those 2cp for best practices :)